# How to limit search results based on manual filters?

Tags: google-places-api

Is there any way to only show place results based on a pre-defined (manual) list of place ID's? That is, I don't only want to limit results to a specific country, city or type. Let's say for example I want to create a web app where one can search among x number of places I love. I'd like to manually select these and limit results thereafter. I would need to manually create a subset or something like that? Any advice on how and if this can be done?

I have not tried yet, as I am exploring the option.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow! My advise would be to try it out first, then show us some code here and we'll see what things to work / improve on. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get you started on asking here. Also please do also read on how to include a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on your question.